# How long does it take to learn Brazilian Portuguese if I speak Spanish on a B2 level?

Tags: multiple-languages, spanish, portuguese

I speak Spanish on a B2 level. How many months does it take to learn Brazilian Portuguese if I already speak Spanish?

Comment: I took the trouble to answer  your question. It would be nice if you would react.

Answer (score 1):

This question can only be answered as a opinion.

Portuguese and Spanish are not the same language.

**Though they have some things in common**, quite a lot of the vocabulary differs in the two languages.

And you can get into major issues when words appear to mean the same thing and don't.

Also, Iberian Portuguese and its African offshoots versus Brazilian Portuguese differ from each other in pronunciation a great deal. Likewise, Spanish pronunciation also has regional differences.

I speak both and interpret into and out of both (into English), and I do not think one can learn a language in months. To be proficient in a language takes years not months and would include spending time in a country where the language is spoken.

It is possible that a 100% native Spanish or Portuguese speaker can learn the other language more easily but it will not help an intermediate speaker of either to learn the other. The differences and commonalities cannot be grasped unless one speaks one language natively or very fluently.

My personal experience is that I learned Portuguese as a child and did not learn Spanish until much later. It took a lot of effort on my part to keep the two in separate compartments. Many speakers of both either have an accent in one or the other or can't keep the grammar completely separate.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to read Portuguese, you can already do it. The two languages are quite similar in vocabulary.

The pronunciation is another story. There are a lot more vowels and dialectical variations in Portuguese than in Spanish, and it can be tricky finding out which concepts to unlearn and which ones to maintain (estoy vs estou but está and está, for instance).

Comment: Welcome to Language Learning! I noticed that you've recently posted several answers. Some of those really look like one-line comments, failing to address questions (or are only tangentially relative). Please note that **every** answer on this site must address the original Q and stand on its own on addressing it (e.g. not be a commentary to the Q or to another A). Also, while your personal experience is valuable, we prefer answers that are **based on facts and references, preferably on academic research**. Your experience/opinion can be part of it, but can't be the whole basis of your post.

Comment: There are many false cognates between the two: https://blog.pi.senac.br/falsos-cognatos-em-espanhol-que-confundem-os-brasileiros/ And that can get you into a lot of trouble. Like with botar.